# Can i call a single document MFC from dialog MFc?

Tags: mfc

i have to draw something in dialog box mfc , so , can i call a single document (because i know how to draw in single document MFC  ) , from  my main dialog box ? 
thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same drawing code both in a `CView` and in a `CDialog`.

On the `CView` drawing works like this:

```
void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pdc)
{
    // Draw something on pdc
    Draw(pdc);
}
```

In a `CDialog`, override the `OnPaint()` handler, and draw like this:

```
void CMyDialog::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CPaintDC* pdc = &dc;
    CDialog::OnPaint();
    // Draw something on pdc
    Draw(pdc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a view in a dialog box, use a window derived from CStatic and make it to the size of dialog box on OnSize.  It will be better than adding a view in a dialog box.

You have to override the OnPaint() event of the static control. To avoid flicker you have to override OnEraseBkgrnd() event.

```
class CMyStatic : public CStatic
{
public:
    CMyStatic ()
        ~CMyStatic();
protected:
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    void Draw(CDC *pDC);
};

void CMyStatic::Draw(CDC *pDC)
{

}
void CMyStatic::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    Draw(&dc);
}
```